# Не находит ключ в словаре

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, методы

```
response = requests.post("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getAll?count=1&access_token=TOKEN&v=5.131").json()
while ik0 != 981:
  print(response['count'][0])
```

После такого кода выдаёт:

> KeyError: 'count'.

Если же убрать `['count'][0]`, то оно выдаст ответ JSON, но я не понимаю почему он не находит ключ, ведь он есть.
Ответ от `api.vk.com`:

```json
{
  'response':{
    'count': 50844,
    'items': [
      {
        'album_id': 284102161,
        'date': 1653221242,
        'id': 457301971,
        ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Потому что в показанном вами словаре есть только один-единственный ключ `response`

Comment: А как получить 'count' из response?

Comment: Из соответствующего словаря и получить `print(response['response']['count'])`

Comment: Спасибо, я так и сделал до Вашего ответа, теперь код работает стабильно. Благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было изменить print на:

```
print(response['response']['count'])
```